# Slider control in Action Sheet

Tags: ios, swift

I just did a research to see if it is possible to create an Action Sheet that does not only show buttons but also sliders that can be toggled.
Does anyone know if this is doable with the standard iOS framework or a 3rd party library?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Maybe not an action sheet, but you can with a popover. The biggest difference between them is an action sheet is **truly** modal - meaning you have to tap on a button to clear it.